# cx Oracle in PyScript

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle, pyenv, pyscript

everyone!

I start now some tests in PyScript with my Oracle DB, but the cx oracle not work

```
  <head>
    <title>cx test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-env>
      - cx-Oracle
      - pandas
    </py-env>
    </head>
    <body>
      <py-script>
        con = cx_Oracle.connect('cthaeh/####@localhost')
        print('Sucess')
      </py-script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I try things like "cx-Oracle", "cx-oracle","cx_oracle" but doesnt works and i cant find any documentation of libs in Py-env or Oracle in Py-Script.

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Open the browser debugger and post the error messages in your question.

Comment: I have more questions than answers: How did you install the cx_Oracle and Pandas modules?  Can PyScript load binary modules?  And if it can, can it load external Oracle Client libraries?  Finally, you should upgrade cx_Oracle to the latest release, now called 'python-oracledb' and imported as `oracledb`.  This is still a binary module but won't need Oracle Client libraries for many applications. See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)